# How to create a custom button in Order grid in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.8, product, orders, controllers, order-grid

I want to create a custom button in magento 1 backend in `**order tab.**`
[image: locatation wanted for the button]
I want this button to be General(for all orders), but i can't find anything related to my issue. All i find it's this article [article](https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-button-to-admin-containers/), but it not help me to much because they create a button for product catalog tab.

Dose anyone know what steps i need to follow to do this? Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: use `adminhtml/sales_order` instead of `adminhtml/catalog_product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code :

You need to first overwrite observer :  **adminhtml_widget_container_html_before**

```
<adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    <observers>
         <add_button_test>
             <class>your_module_name/observer</class>
             <method>addNewButton</method>
         </add_button_test>
    </observers>
</adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
```

After This open Observer file from model which is you overwrite :

```
public function addNewButton($observer)
{
    $container = $observer->getBlock();
    if(null !== $container && $container->getType() == 'adminhtml/sales_order') {
        $data = array(
            'label'     => 'My button',
            'class'     => 'some-class',
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\' '  . Mage::getUrl('*/*', array('param' => 'value')) . '\')',
        );
        $container->addButton('my_button_identifier', $data);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Clear Cache and Refresh order Grid.

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: if i add this code, i can send my button to a controller?

Comment: yes you can just set your controller action in setLocation